# Comment lines in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Please see the blow image]

How to add comment line same as vs code editor image.

Example : General setup!

Comment: you can use the Hypersnips extension and write a dynamic snippet

Answer (score -1):

I think that this is possible with a vscode extension. You could try [Doxygen Documentation Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen) for c/c++.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).